# What are the extrinsic and intrinsic parameters of the two color cameras used for KITTI stereo 2015 dataset

Tags: image-processing, camera, dataset, kitti

I am working with KITTI stereo 2015 data set (http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_scene_flow.php?benchmark=stereo) with color images from  the two cameras(cam2 and cam3) mounted on the roof. I would like to know their **intrinsic and extrinsic parameters**.
There are two calibration folder given: one is **calib** and it has **.txt** file with parameters:

```
P0: 7.070912e+02 0.000000e+00 6.018873e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 7.070912e+02 1.831104e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
P1: 7.070912e+02 0.000000e+00 6.018873e+02 -3.798145e+02 0.000000e+00 7.070912e+02 1.831104e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
P2: 7.070912e+02 0.000000e+00 6.018873e+02 4.688783e+01 0.000000e+00 7.070912e+02 1.831104e+02 1.178601e-01 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 6.203223e-03
P3: 7.070912e+02 0.000000e+00 6.018873e+02 -3.334597e+02 0.000000e+00 7.070912e+02 1.831104e+02 1.930130e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 3.318498e-03
```

and the other folder is **data_scene_flow_calib** and it has two sub folders for **training** and **testing**. Inside training folder there is a folder called **calib_cam_to_cam**. Inside this folder there are also .txt file with parameters:

```
calib_time: 09-Jan-2012 13:57:47
corner_dist: 9.950000e-02
S_00: 1.392000e+03 5.120000e+02
K_00: 9.842439e+02 0.000000e+00 6.900000e+02 0.000000e+00 9.808141e+02 2.331966e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
D_00: -3.728755e-01 2.037299e-01 2.219027e-03 1.383707e-03 -7.233722e-02
R_00: 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
T_00: 2.573699e-16 -1.059758e-16 1.614870e-16
S_rect_00: 1.242000e+03 3.750000e+02
R_rect_00: 9.999239e-01 9.837760e-03 -7.445048e-03 -9.869795e-03 9.999421e-01 -4.278459e-03 7.402527e-03 4.351614e-03 9.999631e-01
P_rect_00: 7.215377e+02 0.000000e+00 6.095593e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 7.215377e+02 1.728540e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
S_01: 1.392000e+03 5.120000e+02
K_01: 9.895267e+02 0.000000e+00 7.020000e+02 0.000000e+00 9.878386e+02 2.455590e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
D_01: -3.644661e-01 1.790019e-01 1.148107e-03 -6.298563e-04 -5.314062e-02
R_01: 9.993513e-01 1.860866e-02 -3.083487e-02 -1.887662e-02 9.997863e-01 -8.421873e-03 3.067156e-02 8.998467e-03 9.994890e-01
T_01: -5.370000e-01 4.822061e-03 -1.252488e-02
S_rect_01: 1.242000e+03 3.750000e+02
R_rect_01: 9.996878e-01 -8.976826e-03 2.331651e-02 8.876121e-03 9.999508e-01 4.418952e-03 -2.335503e-02 -4.210612e-03 9.997184e-01
P_rect_01: 7.215377e+02 0.000000e+00 6.095593e+02 -3.875744e+02 0.000000e+00 7.215377e+02 1.728540e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
S_02: 1.392000e+03 5.120000e+02
K_02: 9.597910e+02 0.000000e+00 6.960217e+02 0.000000e+00 9.569251e+02 2.241806e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
D_02: -3.691481e-01 1.968681e-01 1.353473e-03 5.677587e-04 -6.770705e-02
R_02: 9.999758e-01 -5.267463e-03 -4.552439e-03 5.251945e-03 9.999804e-01 -3.413835e-03 4.570332e-03 3.389843e-03 9.999838e-01
T_02: 5.956621e-02 2.900141e-04 2.577209e-03
S_rect_02: 1.242000e+03 3.750000e+02
R_rect_02: 9.998817e-01 1.511453e-02 -2.841595e-03 -1.511724e-02 9.998853e-01 -9.338510e-04 2.827154e-03 9.766976e-04 9.999955e-01
P_rect_02: 7.215377e+02 0.000000e+00 6.095593e+02 4.485728e+01 0.000000e+00 7.215377e+02 1.728540e+02 2.163791e-01 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 2.745884e-03
S_03: 1.392000e+03 5.120000e+02
K_03: 9.037596e+02 0.000000e+00 6.957519e+02 0.000000e+00 9.019653e+02 2.242509e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
D_03: -3.639558e-01 1.788651e-01 6.029694e-04 -3.922424e-04 -5.382460e-02
R_03: 9.995599e-01 1.699522e-02 -2.431313e-02 -1.704422e-02 9.998531e-01 -1.809756e-03 2.427880e-02 2.223358e-03 9.997028e-01
T_03: -4.731050e-01 5.551470e-03 -5.250882e-03
S_rect_03: 1.242000e+03 3.750000e+02
R_rect_03: 9.998321e-01 -7.193136e-03 1.685599e-02 7.232804e-03 9.999712e-01 -2.293585e-03 -1.683901e-02 2.415116e-03 9.998553e-01
P_rect_03: 7.215377e+02 0.000000e+00 6.095593e+02 -3.395242e+02 0.000000e+00 7.215377e+02 1.728540e+02 2.199936e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 2.729905e-03
```

I would like to know, what are the extrinsic and intrinsic parameters of the two color cameras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information yo are looking for is in this paper: http://www.cvlibs.net/publications/Geiger2013IJRR.pdf.

From page 3:

[image: Kitti calibration conventions]

And:

> Here, i ∈ {0, 1, 2, 3} is the camera index, where 0 represents the
>   left grayscale, 1 the right grayscale, 2 the left color and 3 the
>   right color camera.

Kitti images are already undistorted, so the intrinsic parameters are **P_rect_02** and **P_rect_03**.

For the extrinsic calibration, it depends on what do you need. In page 4 of the paper you can find how to project 3D points to different cameras. Usually, 3D GT vaues are in the camera 0 reference frame.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Milo for your answer. I need **(R|t)** rotation and translation matrix as camera extrinsic for color cameras 2 and 3.  any suggestion?

Comment: @Fazan Kabir You need R|t with respect to which reference frame? Could you give more details on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply :) .Suppose I am taking a single colored image **000000_10.png** from the directory **data_stereo_flow\training\colored_0** . I would like to know what will be the camera extrinsic based on this particular image?

What my assumptions are, if I take the calibration file **(000000.txt)** from the directory **data_scene_flow_calib\training\calib_cam_to_cam** then like you have mentioned above **R_02** will be rotation matrix and **T_02** will be translation matrix : **(R|T)** . But  I am not sure if I am right :(

Comment: @Fazan Kabir: It seems that [R_02|t_02] are *before rectification* and you don't need them *after rectification*. To project points from the camera reference coordinate system into the image of the i-th camera, you are supposed to use P_rect_i * R_rect_0, so you don't have explicitly [R|T] but the full projection: P*[R|T]. After rectification, the cameras are aligned so there is not rotation between them. Also, if you look at the components of  P_rect_i (equation 4 from the paper), you see the baseline b_x_i, which would be the only translation component.

Comment: So, if you really need [R|t] explicitly, with respect to the camera reference coordinate system, it seems to me that it would be: R = R_rect_0, t = [b_x_i, 0, 0]t, but I have not tested it. If you try this, could you please let me know if it works?